# Redirect to a different page from a Ajax Modal

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core, bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages project with a modal based on the
[Bootstrap Modals for Razor Pages project](https://github.com/zbma/razor-pages-bootstrap-ajax-modals). I've also added a razor page for a privacy statement to it.

When the user hits the `OnPostContactModalPartial` action, I want to redirect to the privacy page. So in the GitHub project, I placed the following in `index.cs`:

```
 public IActionResult OnPostContactModalPartial(Contact model)
 {
     …
     return RedirectToPage("Privacy");
 }
```

But in continues loading the page instead of redirecting. Does anybody know how to solve this?

I need to move to another page, because I must logout and go to the first page in the same click.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
Server.Transfer("Privacy");
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: Can you tell me what to install in .net Core to activate Server.Transfer. Can't find the right package or namespace.

Comment: @Dinand: You are right. There isn't a `Server.Transfer()` method in ASP.NET Core. To help avoid confusion with future answers, I've added the `.net-core` and `razor-pages` tags to your post. (You had already stated "Razor pages" but I wanted to make this especially clear to contributors.)

Comment: @Dinand: The comment was for this answer, not for your question.